# List does not properly position around left floating fieldset

Tags: html, css

When fieldset floats left, the bullets of list items appear inside of fieldset. This unexpected effect is especially obvious with Opera:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        fieldset {
            width:50%;
            float:left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>My Field Set</legend>
        field set <br />
        field set <br />
        field set <br />
        field set <br />
        field set <br />
        field set <br />
    </fieldset>
    surround surround surround surround surround surround surround surround surround surround surround 
    <ul>
        <li>first list
        <li>second list
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

For testing, I set fieldset to *float:right*, then list items seem to be properly positioned.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Add padding/margin to the `ul/li`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this to the css :**

```
ul{
    float:left;
}
```